# API.swift file not update : Apollo GraphQL iOS

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo

I am using GraphQL API with iOS project.my .graphql file is,

```
mutation SigninQuery($email: String! , $password: String!) {
    signin(email: $email, password: $password) {
        result {
            token
            firstName
            lastName
            profileImage
        }
    }
}
```

and my files are located in the following order,

Project

- ->appDelegate
- ->info.plist
- ->schema.json
- -->Graphql[Folder]
- ->API.swift
- ->ApiFile.graphql

My API.swift file still exist only with header

> import Apollo

. Anyone can you please help me to findout the solution

Comment: 1. Update your schema.json before build.  
2. Build normally in XCode (if you attach shell script for running GraphQL parser).    
It should update the file `API.swift`.
According to your GraphQL file, you should be able to call the class with name `SigninQueryMutation(email: , password:)`

Comment: @CosmosMan Thank you for your reply but can you please explain me how to update schema.json file...

Comment: What I actually mean by update is to regenerate the `schema.json`.
I think some script is missing in your XCode build phase.
How graphql works is, 
1. You inspect graphql schema and generate it as `schema.json` or  `some_other_name.json`.
2. Then feed that `schema.json` or `some_other_name.json` to your graphql parser to parse your `.graphql` files.

If something missed between `schema.json` and `.graphql` files, it won't work. Something like `isUserPretty` is missing from `user`.
If nothing happened, it should be working fine.

Comment: For example, a script for generating `schema.json` look like this. `apollo-codegen introspect-schema http://www.your-server:8080/graphql --header "Authorization: Bearer  some kind of authorization code" --output schema.json`.

Comment: a script for generating `API.swift` looks like this.
`APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH="$(eval find $FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS -name "Apollo.framework" -maxdepth 1)"
if [ -z "$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH" ]; then
echo "error: Couldn't find Apollo.framework in FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS; make sure to add the framework to your project."
exit 1
fi

cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}"
$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-codegen.sh generate $(find . -name '*.graphql') --schema schema.json --output API.swift`

Comment: What if I don't have Bearer token..Is  any problem ?And What it mean by **"${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}"**is it need to change TARGET_NAME to any other folder name

Comment: Bearer token is not a problem if your server doesn't require auth I think. `cd ${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}` dives into your project source path and the latter command parse every single file ending with `.graphql` into `API.swift`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183486/discussion-between-cosmos-man-and-angel-f-syrus).

Comment: @CosmosMan one more thing can you please show me the .graphql file of the project you tried please....

Comment: I've sent it in chat.

Comment: are you fix this issue please, i have the same issue if you can help

Comment: Yes I fixed the issue. What is your state now??

Comment: I had the same issue. How did you solve that?

Comment: @RaviB Yes I fixed the issue. What is your state now??

Comment: My project generated the API.swift automatically on the build, but it is not updating after the grapql file is added or edited. Can you provide answer of this question

Comment: Did you add the Generate Apollo GRAPHQL API in build phases...and if you, what is the script you given.

Answer (score 0):

If you correct initialized the apollo client, then you won't have such a problem.
I installed **Apollo** using **Swift packages**. I did following steps:

1. Hierarchy

[image]

2. Script to generate `API.swift` (pay attention on folder to generate and name of schema. In my case, folder is *GraphQL* and name is *tetsTet*):

> ```
>     DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE="${BUILD_ROOT}"
>
>      while ! [ -d "${DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE}/SourcePackages" ]; do
>        if [ "${DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE}" = / ]; then
>          echo >&2 "error: Unable to locate SourcePackages directory from BUILD_ROOT: '${BUILD_ROOT}'"
>         exit 1
>        fi
>
>   DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE="$(dirname "${DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE}")"
> done
>
> # Grab a reference to the directory where scripts are checked out
> SCRIPT_PATH="${DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE}/SourcePackages/checkouts/apollo-ios/scripts"
>
> if [ -z "${SCRIPT_PATH}" ]; then
>     echo >&2 "error: Couldn't find the CLI script in your checked out SPM packages; make sure to add the framework to your project."
>     exit 1
> fi
>
> cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}/GraphQL"
> "${SCRIPT_PATH}"/run-bundled-codegen.sh codegen:generate --target=swift --includes=./**/*.graphql --localSchemaFile="tetsTets.json" API.swift
> ```

3. Drag the generated `API.swift` file to your folder

> uncheck the "Copy Files If Needed" checkbox

Comment: What is the difference with:


apollo codegen:generate "Batuta/models/API.swift" --localSchemaFile="Batuta/schema/schema.json" --includes="./**/*.graphql" --target="swift"

Comment: @user3154785 actually, I don't know:) But only this way works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to build my project with autogenerated code

```
apollo codegen:generate --target=swift --includes=CourseQuery.graphql --localSchemaFile="schema.json" API.swift
```

The file `API.swift` is then generated and added to Xcode project.

Building the project I get this error

```
Cannot find type 'GraphQLQuery' in scope
```

This is how the class is defined

```
public final class CourseQuery: GraphQLQuery
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33368707)